# Error while calling class instances

Tags: python, class, pygame

this program I am making in Python 2.7 with Pygame. It's my first attempt to create a game using classes. I am trying to initialize a class with stats for the hero, such as hp, speed, etc named 'archer'. When I try to run the code, it gives me this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/rpg.py", line 85, in <module>
    archer.walk()
NameError: name 'archer' is not defined`

Here is my code.

```
from pygame import *
from random import *
from time import *
import pygame
init()
###############VARIABLES
xmove = 0
ymove = 0
white = ( 255,255,255 )

###############INITIALIZING
def preStuff():
    heroSelect()#choose a hero
    initiateScreen()#set screen size
def initiateScreen():
    screen = display.set_mode ((500,500))
def heroSelect():
    print """ Welcome to Boss Fights!
Select a hero:
Archer: Use a bow for long range attacks! Attacks do little damage, but can hit from far away. Has average health.

Warrior: Smite enemies with his powerful sword! Attacks a very powerful, but have very short range and are quite slow. Has high health.

Assasin: Hit your enemy without them even seeing you! Assasin moves very quickly, and attacks quickly Has low health.

Alien: Blast your enemy with fire! Use a staff to shoot strong fireballs at enemies, with moderate damage and range. Has average health.


"""
    heroC = raw_input('Which class would you like?')
    if heroC == 'Archer' or 'archer' or 'ar':
        archer=Hero(50,250,image.load('archer.png'),100,.3,.1)#initialize Hero as: archer
    elif heroC == 'Warrior' or 'warrior' or 'w':
        warrior=Hero(50,250,image.load('warrior.png'),200,.4,.05)
    elif heroC == 'Assasin' or 'assasin' or 'as':
        assasin=Hero(50,250,image.load('asassin.png'),125,.1,.2)
    elif heroC == 'Alien' or 'alien' or 'al':
        alien=Hero(50,250,image.load('alien.png'),150,.3,.1)



class Hero:    
    def __init__(self,x,y, blitImg,hp,attackspeed,speed):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.blitImg=blitImg
        self.hp = hp
        self.attackspeed = attackspeed
        self.speed=speed

def walk(self):

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()            
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_s:
                ymove = self.speed
            elif event.key == K_w:
                ymove = -self.speed
            elif event.key == K_a:
                xmove = -self.speed
            elif event.key == K_d:
                xmove = self.speed
        elif event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_a or K_s or K_d or K_w:
                xmove = 0
                ymove = 0
    self.y += ymove
    self.x += xmove
    screen.fill( white )
    screen.blit(self.blitImg,(self.x,self.y))
    display.update()






if __name__ == "__main__":
    preStuff()
    while True:
        archer.walk()
```

I am just trying to make the character walk for now.(and just the archer class)
I have tried running

```
archer=Hero(50,250,image.load('archer.png'),100,.3,.1)
```

in the shell, and it works fine. I can call archer.y and the rest of the variables, and they print perfectly. Please someone help me figure out why this isnt working!. (P.S. I am a beginner programmer, so please forgive if it is some simple, easy fix that i'm too dumb to realize)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`archer` is a local variable, and thus isn't visible to the global scope that the last line of your program is operating on. You probably want to make `heroSelect()` return the Hero object that is created, and then have the `preStuff()` method return that as well.

Comment: Ok, so how would I do that? I've never used the return function before, and after researching it, I don't really understand how to use it. Would I just add return archer at the end of heroSelect() and preStuff()?

Comment: at the end of `heroSelect` just add the line `return heroC`. In `preStuff` when you call `heroSelect`, store the output into some variable, i.e. `hero = heroSelect()`, which will give `hero` the value that you reterned from `heroSelect`, and at the end of `preStuff` return this hero variable, i.e. `return hero`